# Trying to find an old offbeat scifi/fantasy book title

Tags: story-identification, cyberpunk

This is a long shot, but I'm trying to find a book I read a decade ago. 
It was science fiction/fantasy, had a review mentioning how it would make a good gift for a unix sysadmin on the front, had a dolphin charm/drug mentioned in it that was like viagra but could only be used twice every decade (because it was magical and dangerous to one's health), and had a scene near the end in which everyone racks the slide on their pump shotguns and then reloads the ejected shell. 
It was in the same vein as snowcrash and neuromancer but with more fantasy elements and a lot more crazy. I think it was written in the 90s. Unfortunately, this is all I can remember about it. I have searched far and wide on the internet and through some of the catalog systems of libraries I may have found it in and found nothing.

Comment: Based entirely off your 'like Snowcrash but crazier' comment - is it anything by Jeff Noon? The description reminds me vaguely of his Vurt, but it's been a long while since I read it.

Comment: Haven't read all of Jeff Noon's output, but nothing like this so far. Not _Vurt_, I've read that.